# Noise in rendered image

Tags: rendering

I have created 3d model of a little boy but when I render it there are small points on the model what can cause it? There is a plane with material of emission.[image]

Comment: Those are fireflies. Mostly because fireflies are light pixels, lighting will help make them less visible. Are you using Cycles? If so, I can help you improve your render.